# Attempting to solve a SAS triangle- getting wrong output using math.cos

Tags: python, math, trigonometry

```
import math
a = 5
b = 7
C = 49

c = (a**2)+(b**2)-(2*a*b*(math.cos(C)))
gc = math.sqrt(c)

print(gc)
```

It outputs 7.27726060671
when it should output something like 5.3. Any help would be very appreciated.

-Cam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [convert to radians](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.acos) first:

Try:

```
c = (a**2)+(b**2)-(2*a*b*(math.cos(math.radians(C))))
print(math.sqrt(c))
#5.29866662196
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was working in circles for hours. Thanks!